# Angular 2+ - Compress json file on buil

Tags: node.js, json, angular, compression, minify

I've my ng7 app and I use ngx-translate for i18n.
I have 3 json files in src/assets/i18n dir with all the app's labels.
Now I wantto minify/compress these files on building phase, how can I do that?

Any suggestion?

Thanks
F